# On the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{f(n)} < \infty$ and the inverse of $f(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that for some increasing function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{f(n)} < \infty$.

Can we say something about the growth of its inverse, i.e. $f^{-1}(x)$?

In particular, I believe that $f^{-1}(x)$ should grow sub-polynomially, i.e. $f^{-1}(x) = o(x)$.

For example, if $f(x) = x^2$, then of course $\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{f(n)} < \infty$, and $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x} = o(x)$. I have a feeling that this should be true but I can't think of a way to prove it.

Comment: So you're assuming that $f$ has an inverse? Also, if you define $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ with $f(n)=n^2$, strictly speaking $f$ doesn't have an inverse, since is not surjective.

Comment: Yes, for now I'm assuming that $f$ has an inverse. For the second comment, since $f(n) = n^2$ is defined for $n \geq 1$, then $f$ has a proper inverse.

Comment: An inverse function of $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ would be a function $g:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that $g(f(n)) = n$ and $f(g(n)) = n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Such inverse doesn't exist for the case $f(n)=n^2$.

Comment: That's true. Sorry my mistake. It should be $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then it makes more sense.

Comment: I agree. You may be also thinking in increasing functions? To avoid many pathological examples....

Comment: Yes, indeed. Again, I just assumed that but forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing those things out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f^{-1}(x) \ne o(x)$.  Then for some $c > 0$ there is an infinite increasing sequence
$x_n \to \infty$ such that $f^{-1}(x_n) \ge c x_n$, i.e. $f(c x_n) \le x_n$.
By taking a subsequence, we can ensure $x_{n+1} \ge 2 x_n$ and $x_n > 6/c$.
Now for $c x_{n-1} \le j < c x_{n}$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{f(j)} \ge \frac{1}{f(c x_n)} \ge \frac{1}{x_n} $$
and since there are at least $c x_n - c x_{n-1}-1$ such $j$,
$$ \eqalign{ \sum_{c x_{n-1} \le j < c x_n} \frac{1}{f(j)} &\ge \frac{c x_n - c x_{n-1} - 1}{x_n}\ge \frac{c}{2} - \frac{1}{x_n}\cr
&> \frac{c}{3} \cr} $$
Therefore $\sum_j 1/f(j) = \infty$.